# plotting monthly and yearwise weather data in r

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I am trying to develop a weather plot like that appears in weather data - something like.

[image]

I want to plot daily value (although average value can appear in circle).  I am using ggplot2 as it need multifaceted (for each month and year).

```
st <- as.Date ("2009-1-1")
en <- as.Date ("2011-12-28")
date1 <- seq(st, en, "1 day")
year <- format(date1, "%Y")
month <- format (date1, "%b")
day <- as.numeric (format(date1, "%d"))

avgtm <- round (rnorm (length(date1), 50,5), 1)
maxtm <- avgtm + abs(rnorm (length (avgtm), 0, 5))
mintm <-  avgtm - abs(rnorm (length (avgtm), 0, 5))

myd <- data.frame ( year, month, day, avgtm, maxtm, mintm)
require(ggplot2)
qplot(day, avgtm, data = myd, geom = "line", col = "red") +
facet_grid(year ~ month) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

There is one major problem here, line will connect between months.

Each month is plotted to maximum (although one month can end in 28, leaving blank at the month).
[image]

Is there a smart way to achieve what I want to achieve. I tried ggplot2 but there might be other nice options.

**Edit:**

I am trying to add vertical line at the first day of month to demark the months. Here is I tried to find the first day of month:

```
 td = as.Date (seq(as.Date("2009/1/1"), as.Date("2011/12/28"), "months"))
```

I tried to use this to plot line:

```
qplot(date, avgtm, data = myd, geom = "line", col = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~year, scales='free_x', ncol=1, nrow=3) +

   geom_vline(xintercept=td, linetype="dotted") + theme_bw()
```

But running an error:
Error : Invalid intercept type: should be a numeric vector, a function, or a name of a function

How can plot the vertical line with the date ?

Comment: The line for each year is continues so that we can see the trend between last day of month to start day of consecutive month

Comment: Have a LOOK at this: http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.com/2013/04/rg82-time-series-plot-weather-data-with.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a solution with  `panel.xblocks` from `latticeExtra`:

```
st <- as.Date("2009-1-1")
en <- as.Date("2011-12-28")
date1 <- seq(st, en, "1 day")

avgtm <- round (rnorm (length(date1), 50,5), 1)

myd <- data.frame(date1, avgtm)
```

I define two functions to extract month and year values instead of
including them in the `data.frame`. This approach is useful with 
`panel.xblocks` in the `panel` function of `xyplot`:

```
month <- function(x)format(x, '%m')
year <- function(x)format(x, '%Y')
```

I use `year(date1)` as conditioning variable to produce three
panels. Each of these panels will display the time series for that
year (`panel.xyplot`) and a sequence of contiguous blocks with
alternating colors to highlight months (`panel.xblocks`). You
should note that the `y` argument in `panel.xblocks` is the
function `month` previously defined:

```
xyplot(avgtm ~ date1 | year(date1), data=myd,
       type='l', layout=c(1, 3),
       scales=list(x=list(relation='free')),
       xlab='', ylab='',
       panel=function(x, y, ...){
           panel.xblocks(x, month,
                         col = c("lightgray", "white"),
                         border = "darkgray")
           panel.xyplot(x, y, lwd = 1, col='black', ...)
           })
```

[image: xblocks]

Answer (score 4):

How about making a date column, then faceting on year only

```
myd$date <- as.Date(paste(myd$year, myd$month, myd$day), format='%Y %b %d')

qplot(date, avgtm, data = myd, geom = "line", col = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~year, scales='free_x', ncol=1, nrow=3)
```

[image]

You could add `scales='free_x'` to your plot as well, but will find it makes interpretation difficult.

By faceting on month and year you are telling the viewer and the plotting tool that the variables plotted are not continuous.  This is incorrect as you've pointed out in your question.  Thus, no faceting... You can add tick marks for each month or each day if you want.

```
library(scales)
qplot(date, avgtm, data = myd, geom = "line", col = "red") +
      facet_wrap(~year, scales='free_x', ncol=1, nrow=3) +
      scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("month"), labels=date_format("%b"))
```

Alternatively you could extract `day of year` and plot everything on one plot, coloring by year:

```
myd$doy <- format(myd$date, '%j')
p <- ggplot(myd, aes(x=doy, y=avgtm, color=year, group=year))

p + geom_line()
```

or

```
p + geom_smooth()
```

Comment: @Justin thanks - seems an alternative, tough loose nice anotations for month at the top

Comment: @Justin thanks justin for the solution and suggestion, someway we can add vertical line at end of month, so that we follow the month more clearly, put text label for month

Comment: my solution with `library(scales)` does this.  Otherwise, you can fiddle with the `theme_bw` or draw lines using `geom_hline`... but I'd suggest the theme option.

Comment: The error tells you, it needs to be numeric vector, not dates... which is why I suggested working with the `theme` instead of trying to draw your own lines.  (add a line like `theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour='blue'))`).  And take a look at the `theme` [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html)